# How to validate a limit on each instance of the association, but not the association itself in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, simple-form

I have a `Product` model and each product can have many options, such, as size and color. Each `Option` can also have many `Choices`. So the "Size" `Option` might have "Small," "Medium," and "Large" as `Choices` and the "Color" option might have "Red" and "Blue" as choices.

Using [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) I'm essentially trying to do something like this on the Product form:

The problem is that if the user has multiple product options (Such as size and Color), it only gives them one radio button across each set of `Options`. So they could select "Blue" but not "Blue" and "XL," for instance.

The other thing I could do is use `as: :check_boxes` instead of `as: :radio_buttons` but then the user could select more than one color (e.g. red and blue), when only one choice should be allowed for each option.

So what is the best "Rails" way to validate a limit on each instance of the association, but not the association itself? I could do this in javascript on the client side if I have to, but that seems less safe than having the validation on the server side.

Plus the `Product` should be able to have many `Choices`. So it's not really a validation on the association between `Products` and `Choices`, but rather a validation on limiting to 1 `Choice` for each set of choices that are available through the `Options` model.

For instance, a T-Shirt might be Red and XL, but it shouldn't be allowed to be Red & Blue + Small & XL?

Here are my models:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :choices,  through: :options
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  has_many :choices
end

class Choice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
end
```

Comment: You need js for the UI and then received params in the backend must be checked to validate the data..

Comment: Thanks Arup. I guess my question is how to check the data on the backend?

Comment: This is a call for custom validation..

Comment: I'm not sure of the attributes, but you could try a unique index in a migration. And depending on the attributes, you could make a unique clustered index maybe. That could limit the options on the back end for you.

Comment: I guess that's the heart of my question. How would you do this type of custom validation?

Comment: Sounds like you need another model (eg. `Selection`) which references `Choice` and `Option`. Then you can use a simple scope on the uniqueness validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a customer is suppose to order/select a product with specifications, you may actually need a joining model (Selection/Order) instead of applying validations to the Product model. The Product model seems like it's there just for you to setup the options and choices that the user can select for that product.

If that's the actual case here, you would just create the joining model and just set it up with a polymorphic "feature." Something like this:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :featurable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  validates_inclusion_of :featurable_type, in: %w[Option Choice]
end
```

Newer Rails versions will validate that the `belongs_to` fields are present.

I say polymorphic because I'm assuming that the option may not have choices and sometimes you could just select the option itself. If all options will have choices, then just change the `belongs_to :featurable` to `belongs_to :choice` and remove the inclusions validation. The `belongs_to :user` is there since I assume a specific user would put in this order/selection.

If you may have multiple option choices selected for your product, then you may structure it more like this:

```
class ProductOrder
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :choice_selections
end

class ChoiceSelection
  belongs_to :product_order
  belongs_to :featurable, polymorphic: true

  validates_inclusion_of :featurable_type, in: %w[Option Choice]
  validate :unique_option

  def option
    featurable.is_a?(Option) ? featurable : featurable.option
  end

  def unique_option
    return unless product_order.choice_selections.find_by(option: option).present?
    errors.add(:base, 'choice option must be unique')
  end
end
```

**If all options will have choices:**

You wouldn't need a polymorphic association.

```
class ProductOrder
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :choice_selections
end

class ChoiceSelection
  belongs_to :product_order
  belongs_to :choice
  belongs_to :option

  validates_uniqueness_of :option, scope: :product_order
end
```

**However, to answer the question you've posted above:**

The first thing I'd do is create a custom validation in the Product model.

Be sure to add the `has_many :options` line in the Product model so it looks more like this:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :options
  has_many :choices, through: :options
end
```

Otherwise, that `through` may not work.

Then, add the validation like so:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

   validate :one_choice_per_option

   private

   def one_choice_per_option
     if options.any? { |option| option.choices.count > 1 }
       errors.add(:options, 'can only have one choice')
     end
   end

  # ...
end
```

Please note that this validation will prevent you from creating more than one choice for your product options. I do hope it gives you a better idea on how to create custom validations. I would highly recommend reevaluating your database structure to separate product/option/choice setup and user selections.

If this validation is something that you may use in other models, you may want to consider making is a [validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).

Comment: Thanks this helps! It's for admins who set up products, not ordering. They need to be able to create multiple choices for each option. I'm having trouble understanding why it would need to be polymorphic. But I need them to be able to create multiple choices from the product form, then assign only one choice to each "variant." I think what @fylooi is saying in the comments might be the right approach? I "need another model (eg. Selection) which references Choice and Option. Then you can use a simple scope on the uniqueness validation". Does that seem like the right approach to the database?

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly - please see the "I say polymorphic because I'm assuming..." portion for why it could be polymorphic. If you follow up questions to that, let me know.

Comment: @LeeMcAlilly - I've added a non-polymorphic example. See "If all options will have choices:" section. I've also added validation examples to the polymorphic side to keep option choices unique.

Comment: I tried your custom validation and I can't figure out how to limit to to just saving one choice per option. It only allows me to save one choice in total. I guess what I'm essentially trying to do on the Variant model is something like `validates :choices,    presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :option}` but that doesn't work as well. Is the only way to do this to create a new `Selection` table?